# embed private drupal content (view) at an external site

Tags: views, nodes

this is my situation:
I have a calendar view that displays events, some of them are public and some others are private, I managed to create a view that I can embed at an external site, but this works only for public events, so I'm looking for a way of making the private events be visible also, at the external site you have to log in to see this embeded view from drupal, but those users do not belong to drupal data base, so I was thinking of create a generic user able to see the private content in drupal, so at the external site code this user some way to show the private content at the external site, I hope I'm clear enough.

I've been looking for moduls to do this, but the only thing I found was for D6 and I'm not pretty sure it was the answer to my need.

Thanks.

Comment: what module did you find for d6 (might help guide you to a more recent option)? what version of Drupal is this for (you don't specify)? how you making items "private" and "public"?

Comment: This is the one I've found https://www.drupal.org/project/access_private  thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, using an embeding code I imagine something like this:`<iframe src="http://example.com/embedingnode" usr="guest" pwd="guest"></iframe>`, or some sort of similar code.....